# How to define a parameter with both Optional and PatternTest

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

Why this doesn't work?

```
k[x_Integer:2?(#>0&)]:=x^2
k[]  (*should be 4*)
k[2] (*should be 4*)
```

These following are all working as expected:

```
(* with Optional *)
f[x_Integer:2]:=x^2
f[]
(* with PatternTest *)
g[x_Integer?(#>0&)]:=x^2
g[2]
(* with Optional + Condition *)
h[x_Integer:2]:=x^2/;x>0
h[]
h[2]
```

Comment: `ClearAll[k];
k[x : _Integer?(# > 0 &) : 2] := x^2`?

Comment: That can also be written as `k[x : _Integer?Positive : 2] := x^2`

Comment: ... or `ClearAll[k2];k2[Optional[x_Integer?Positive, 2]] := x^2`

Comment: see `k[x_Integer: 2?(# > 0 &)] // FullForm`  and `Precedence /@ {Optional, Pattern, PatternTest}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `:` can have two meanings in an argument form, `Optional` and `Pattern`, and the front-end has trouble deciding which is meant when two `:` appear in such an argument.

You can fix the issue by writing `Optional` in full form. Like so:

```
Clear[k]; k[Optional[x_Integer?Positive, 2]] := x^2; {k[], k[2], k[-2], k[2.]
```

> `{4, 4, k[-2], k[2.]}`

You might also want to consider some alternatives.

```
Clear[k]; k[x_Integer : 2] /; x > 0 := x^2  
Clear[k]; k[x_ : 2] /; x ∈ PositiveIntegers := x^2
Clear[k]; Default[k] = 2; k[x_.] /; x ∈ PositiveIntegers := x^2
```